# Microk8s session affinity setup only for one session

Tags: kubernetes, stateful

If I have a stateful service, for example, a kalman filter with **lots of** state information and it's time consuming to store and resume the state.
Then I want to deploy the service using Microk8s and each pod will run one container of the above service. Assume there are two pods running and they are PodA and PodB.
When user1 tries to access the service and it's being directed to PodA. Then before the session ends, the user1 should always be directed to PodA and no other users can use the PodA. Then, after user1 has done with the service, a new user can be directed to PodA and use the service. However, if now the user1 want to use the service again, it will still be directed to PodA which is taken by others. How can I make user1 be directed to PodB automatically in this case?

One possible solution could be setting cookie affinity expiring time small. But I want to support **pause** function for my service, which allows the user pause for some time before next request. In that case, the small cookie affinity expiring time won't work.

Comment: I doubt this exists. You have to implement a custom reverse-proxy for this that does per-user-routing. Cloud Native services typically does not work this way, they typically use multithreaded Pods, where each users logic is handled by its own thread, and not by its own Pod.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try to deploy my service in another way.